# Can't Find the solution of Following Error

Tags: javascript, java, sails.js

debug: Deprecated:   `config.adapters`
debug: (see http://links.sailsjs.org/docs/config/connections)
debug: For now, I'll pretend you set `config.connections`.

debug: Deprecated:   `config.adapters.*.module`
debug: (see http://links.sailsjs.org/docs/config/connections)
debug: For now, I'll pretend you set `config.connections["connection"].adapter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an error, sails warn you because you use `config.adapters` wich is deprecated and you should use `config.connections`. This feature will be removed in the future...

[Here](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-connections) is a link on how you should configure your connections to database

What is your version of sails ?

N.B. : You put "java" as a tag, javascript is not related to java.